# Xamarin.forms youtube video

Tags: youtube, xamarin.forms

I know this question has been asked before but I can't seem to find a satisfactory answer. First off I'm very new to Xamarin.forms and mobile app development in general. I'm working on a small time sensitive project. One of the requirements is to have a youtube video play from within the app in both iOS and Android (the link to the youtube video comes from a DB). I used a WebView but it doesn't seem to work well in Android. I also came across the following in another thread:

"When it comes to streaming video on iOS and Android playing that content in a Webview control with or without Xamarin.Forms would be the incorrect choice. Webviews vary on each device and their codec support for HTML5 and H264 video also vary. Both iOS and Android have their own native video players that can play and stream video.

For iOS you have a few options such as AVPlayer or MPMoviePlayerController: http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/video_and_photos/

For Android you could simply use the default VideoView http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/media/video/play_video/ or you could use the binding around the new ExoPlayer: https://github.com/martijn00/ExoPlayerXamarin

You would simply need a custom renderer to bring these into Xamarin.Forms, which would be very simple to do"

I've never done Xamarin.iOS nor Xamarin.Android development before. If someone can provide a simple prototype then that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at "Delivering Rich Media Experiences with the Xamarin.Forms Video Player" (https://blog.xamarin.com/delivering-rich-media-experiences-xamarin-forms-video-player/). Github: https://github.com/adamfisher/Xamarin.Forms.VideoPlayer

Comment: I did come across this component made by Adam Fisher. Is there is a free version of this?

Comment: No, there is not free version (only trial), but it worths $.

Comment: Please note that the video player control is now OSS!